# Error message in beamer due to \framebox

Tags: beamer, errors

Have a look at the code below. It keeps giving me an error and I don't know why. All I know is that it is due to the `\framework` function. Does somebody have an idea how this can be solved?

```
\begin{frame}[t]{Bootstrap}
\begin{itemize}
\item Compute variability of parameter by means of resampling with replacement
\item Standard error necessary to compute prediction error 
\item Algorithm Efron and Tibshirani (1994) 
\item $\hat{\theta^{*}}(b) = s(x^{*b})$
\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[ball]

\framebox{
\item \textbf{Step 1} Select B independent bootstrap samples $x^{*1}$, $x^{*2}$,...  $x^{*B}$ each consisting of n data values drawn with replacement from $x$  
}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\framebox` won't work here. It will frame short texts and long texts will be placed on one line protrudint into the margin. Besides this, trying to frame the item label using `\framebox{\item...}` gives the error you are getting.

You can use a `\parbox` to enclose the `\item` contents beforehand:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]{Bootstrap}
\begin{itemize}
\item Compute variability of parameter by means of resampling with replacement
\item Standard error necessary to compute prediction error 
\item Algorithm Efron and Tibshirani (1994) 
\item $\hat{\theta^{*}}(b) = s(x^{*b})$
\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[ball]
%
\item \framebox{\parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax}{\textbf{Step 1} Select B independent bootstrap samples $x^{*1}$, $x^{*2}$,...  $x^{*B}$ each consisting of n data values drawn with replacement from $x$}%
}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, you can define a command if you need to use this several times. For example,

```
\newcommand\FText[1]{%
  \framebox{\parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax}{#1}}%
}
```

and then

```
\item \FText{\textbf{Step 1} Select B independent bootstrap samples $x^{*1}$, $x^{*2}$,...  $x^{*B}$ each consisting of n data values drawn with replacement from $x$}
```

Notice that just the contents was boxed, not the whole `\item`; otherwise, you'll get the wrong alignment for the itemize labels.

If you want to enclose also the item label, some additional work will be required:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\newcounter{tmp}
\newcommand\FText[1]{%
\stepcounter{tmp}%
\tikzmark{start-\thetmp}#1\tikzmark{end-\thetmp}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw
  ([xshift=-15pt,yshift=2.3ex]pic cs:start-\thetmp) 
    rectangle 
  ([yshift=-1ex]current page text area.east|-{pic cs:end-\thetmp});
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]{Bootstrap}
\begin{itemize}
\item Compute variability of parameter by means of resampling with replacement
\item Standard error necessary to compute prediction error 
\item Algorithm Efron and Tibshirani (1994) 
\item $\hat{\theta^{*}}(b) = s(x^{*b})$
\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[ball]
%
\item \FText{\textbf{Step 1} Select B independent bootstrap samples $x^{*1}$, $x^{*2}$,...  $x^{*B}$ each consisting of n data values drawn with replacement from $x$}

\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The code needs two or three runs to stabilize.